# Finding variables that lie on a straight line given ratio of line width.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I can do this question, but I was massively over-complicating it, I'm hoping someone can point out the obvious.... I used substitution of two variables but took a lot of arranging. But my workings must've been worth about 10 marks when the question's only worth $3$... So basically I must've over complicated it... :( Please help!

The points $A, B$ and $C$ lie in order on a straight line.

The coordinates of $A$ are $(2, 5)$

The coordinates of $B$ are $(4, p)$

The coordinates of $C$ are $(q, 17)$

Given that $AC = 4(AB)$ , find the values of $p$ and $q$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow{AC}=\binom{q-2}{12}=4\overrightarrow{AB}=4\binom{2}{p-5}$$

Therefore, $q=10$ and $p=8$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $m_{\vec{AB}} = \dfrac{p-5}{4-2} = \dfrac{p-5}{2}=m_{\vec{BC}}= \dfrac{17-p}{q-4}$ since $A,B, C$ are collinear. Also: $AC^2 = 16AB^2\implies (17-5)^2+(q-2)^2 = 16((p-5)^2+(4-2)^2)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand the top, but I wouldn't know where to go with the bottom equation, my intuition would be to re-arange to make either p or q and sub into the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit in the given information is the following triangle from which we immediately infer that $q=10$.

Then we have

$$ \frac{p-5}{4-2}=\frac{17-5}{10-2} $$

which quickly leads to $p=8$.

[image: triangle]